# How can I make the CSS attribut of a Div to change when there is a text overflow on another Div?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm building a Div with column-count = 2, column-fill = auto, and a height = 100%.

This Div will contain some other Div with text inside.
However, I want my page to be fluid and adapt automatically when the window get shorter in order that overflowing text could be read on the 2 columns by using the browser scrollbar.

So I need my Div to remove height = 100% and replace it with min-height = 100% in order that a scrollbar appear on the browser to allow to read below the overflowing text on 2 column instead of having the overflowing text appearing on third column (despite column-count = 2).

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS only or should I need Javascript, and how ?

Many Thanks

Comment: May be I am missing something; but wouldn't it be ok to have min-height: 100% always, and do not set height at all ?

Comment: If I do that (min-height=100%), then column-fill=auto will not work (columns will be balanced) because the height is not set; so he can't calculated at what height to start filling the second column.